# Error de compilación en una clase de Java

Tags: java, java-8, compilar

Hola quería saber por que me aparece este error: `Error:(64, 8) java: class, interface, or enum expected`

Esta es la clase a la que da ese error de compilación: package com.company;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class personaje {

    private int salud, ataque, fuerza, ph, nivel;
    private String nombre;
    private Random rand= new Random(System.nanoTime());

//Getters y Setters
    public int getSalud() {
        return salud;
    }

    public void setSalud(int salud) {
        this.salud = salud;
    }

    public int getAtaque() {
        return ataque;
    }

    public void setAtaque(int ataque) {
        this.ataque = ataque;
    }

    public int getFuerza() {
        return fuerza;
    }

    public void setFuerza(int fuerza) {
        this.fuerza = fuerza;
    }

    public int getPh() {
        return ph;
    }

    public void setPh(int ph) {
        this.ph = ph;
    }

    public int getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }

    public void setNivel(int nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}

public int attack_fisico () {

    int aleatorio = rand.nextInt(2);
    return nivel * ataque * aleatorio;
}

    public int attack_fuerza (){
        if(ph>0){
            ph--;
            return nivel*fuerza;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void daño (int salud) {
        this.salud -= salud;
    }
```

Estoy aprendiendo Java recién, si me pueden explicar que hice mal me ayudaría mucho, Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas 3 funciones:

```
public int attack_fisico () {

    int aleatorio = rand.nextInt(2);
    return nivel * ataque * aleatorio;
}

public int attack_fuerza (){
   if(ph>0){
       ph--;
       return nivel*fuerza;
   } else {
       return 0;
   }
}

public void daño (int salud) {
   this.salud -= salud;
}
```

Están fuera de la clase. Toda función debe pertenecer a una clase.

Answer (score 0):

Concuerdo con @**gbianchi**.

> Estoy aprendiendo Java recién, si me pueden explicar que hice mal me ayudaría mucho, Gracias!

Como consejo puedo decirte que:

Adicionalmente las clases **SIEMPRE** empiezan con mayúscula para seguir un estándar en programación y cuando otra persona lea tu código pueda saber que es una clase por el simple hecho de empezar con Mayúscula, por lo que **personaje** debería ser **Personaje**

```
public class personaje {
```

Por

```
public class Personaje {
```

Comment: No. los nombres son como una quiera. Empezar las clases con mayuscula (o cualquier cosa) no es un requisito, es solo una convencion de codigo. mira: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947084/why-should-the-first-letter-of-a-java-class-be-upper-cased

Comment: Esa es la idea, que vaya sobre el estándar... Si se programara como uno quisiera sería muy complicado luego leerlo. Edito mi respuesta no como algo que provoque el error de compilación, pero si como un consejo.

Answer (score 0):

tienes un corchete en el lugar incorrecto aqui:

```
   public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}   // aqui
```

como ves esta luego del cierre de **setNombre** lo que viene siendo un corchete de cierre de la clase, dejando invalidos los 3 ultimos metodos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]